# I can't access my flask application from the generated url on my local machine

Tags: python, windows, flask, visual-studio-code

Browser Error  Message:

> "This site can’t be reachedThe webpage at http://0.0.0.0:9696/ might
> be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web
> address. ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID"

My code:

```
import pickle
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from model_files.ml_model import predict_mpg

app = Flask("mpg_prediction")

app.route('/', methods= ['POST'])

def predict():
    vehicle_configuration = request.get_json()

    with open('./model_files/mpg_model.bin', 'rb') as f_in:
        mpg_model = pickle.load(f_in)
        f_in.close()

    predictions = predict_mpg(vehicle_configuration,mpg_model)

    response = {'mpg_predictions': list(predictions)
    }
    return jsonify(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug= True , host= '0.0.0.0' , port=9696)
```

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 1):

Supplying `host='0.0.0.0'` means to listen on all network interfaces. Note that this means that anyone on the same network can also access the site! For debugging, you probably want `host='127.0.0.1'` or `host='localhost'` instead, which limits access to your own computer only.

In either case, your computer's local IP address is not `0.0.0.0`. Use `127.0.0.1:9696` or `localhost:9696` in your browser to access the site.